# how to send daily post on facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

hi 
please if anyone knows that tell me how to send daily post to application user's wall using facebook application. i need a PHP script how to post message user wall.

thanks

Comment: You should ask it on [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) instead of here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This question is supposed to be asked on StackOverflow*

However, the Facebook documentation has an [php example](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for this. You can also use [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) for this.

For publishing to user's wall your app need to have publish_stream Extended permission and then you can issue a POST request to http://graph.facebook.com/[username/userID]/feed

Like:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed
```

Comment: Ok but withing this example i don't have any idea. what is this ?? is this PHP code or python code?can you explain this clearly? because i'm new to facebook application development

Comment: Why downvote..[curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is in php library. I don't kno php so i have no idea of syntax.. but its as mentioned in Facebook doc

Answer (score 1):

U could make a cron job that runs a php script to make it post to your facebook

Comment: i know the way to do it but don't know how to send ntification without prompt message box

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post directly to the user's wall without first asking for the *publish_stream* permission during the app authorization process.

You can find more information on permissions here - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Also note that Facebook recommends a "user-initiated" sharing process. Which means, even if the user gives you the *publish_stream* permission, you'll probably get into trouble if you start spamming the user's wall every day without the user taking any significant action on your application.

Comment: i didn't ask about issues of facebook privacy. i just want to know how to post someone else wall.